# Show $pq\mid a^{pq} -a^q -a^p +a$ if $p\neq q$ are prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes and $a$ be any integer then $a^{pq} -a^q -a^p +a$ is divisible by $pq$.

Factorising we get $a^{pq} -a^q -a^p +a =a^p(a^q -1) - a(a^{q-1}-1)$ and we know $p \mid a^{p-1}-1$ and $q \mid a^{q-1}-1$.

I can't proceed further with the proof. Please Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint** Look at this $\pmod{p}$ and $\pmod{q}$. If you prove that your expression is $0$ in both modular arithmetics, you are done.

$\pmod{p}$ you have $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$ therefore you also have
$$(a^p)^q \equiv a^q \pmod{p}$$

$\pmod{q}$ you can do a similar computation.

Answer (score 2):

For prime $q,$ 
$$a^{pq}-a^q-a^p+a=[(\underbrace{a^p})^q-(\underbrace{a^p})]-[a^q-a]$$

Now by [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html), $b^q\equiv b\pmod q$ where $b$ is any integer

Set $b=a^p, a$

Similarly for prime $p$

Now if $p,q$  both divides $a^{pq}-a^q-a^p+a,$ the later must be divisible by lcm$(p,q)$

Comment: @tone, See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505327/prove-apq-equiv-a-pmod-pq

Answer (score 1):

${\bf Lemma}\ \ {\rm Suppose }\ \ \forall a\!:\ P(a)\equiv a\pmod p$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\ {\rm and}\ \  \forall a\!:\ Q(a)\equiv a\pmod q,\ $ for some polynomials $\,P,Q\in\Bbb Z[x]$
$\text{Then:}\,\bmod pq\!:\ R(a) := P(Q(a))-P(a)-Q(a)+a\equiv 0^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\!\!$
${\bf Proof }\ \ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\,\ R(a) \ \ \equiv\ \ \ Q(a)\  -\quad a\ \ -\ Q(a)+a\equiv 0^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!$
$\ \ \ {\rm and\,\ \ \ mod}\ q\!:\,\ R(a)\ \ \equiv \  \ \ P(a) \ -\ P(a)-\ \ \,a\ \ +\ \, a\equiv 0^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!$
so $\ p,q\mid R(a)\,\Rightarrow\, pq = {\rm lcm}(p,q)\mid R(a)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242). $\  \bf\small QED.\ $ OP has $\, P(a) = a^p,\  Q(a) = a^q.$

---

**Alternatively** $\ \{PQ(a),\ a\}\,\equiv\, \{Q(a), P(a)\}\,$ mod $\,p\,$ & $\,q\,$ so also $\bmod pq,\,$ so their sums are congruent $\!\bmod pq.\,$ This view brings to the fore innate $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetry}$ - see my other answer here.

Comment: See also [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/787204/242)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ \{a^{pq},a\} \equiv \{a^p,a^q\}$ mod $ p,q,\,$ via $\,a^p\equiv a\pmod p,\ a^q\equiv a\pmod q\ $ [little Fermat]

Hence $\, a^{pq}\!+\!a \ \equiv\ a^p\! + a^q\,$ mod $\,p,q,\,$ so also mod $\,pq = {\rm lcm}(p,q)$

since addition $\,f(x,y)\, =\, x + y\,$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetric}$  $\,f(x,y)= f(y,x),\,$  therefore its value depends only upon the (multi-)set $\,\{x,\,y\}.\,$

**Generally** $ $ if a polynomial $\,f\in\Bbb Z[x,y]\,$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetric}$ then

$\qquad\qquad\quad \{A, B\}\, \equiv\, \{a,b\}\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ m,\, n\,\ \Rightarrow\,\  f(A,B)\equiv f(a,b)\, \pmod{\!{\rm lcm}(m,n)}\qquad\quad$

a generalization of the [constant-case optimization  of CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=constant+++optimization++CRT) = Chinese Remainder,  combined with a generalization of the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825833/242) to (symmetric) bivariate polynomials.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/843751/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/787204/242) for generalizations.